# Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit, personal-access-token, git-authentication

Over a long period of time I am using tortoise git, today I am not able to use the tortoise git and getting the below error.

> git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase "origin" remote: Support for
> password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a
> personal access token instead. remote: Please see
> https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information.

I am using the latest tortoise git version.
[image]

I understand about the git latest change. But I want to use tortoise git. Someone, please help me out this issue.

Comment: The error message came from the remote (Github) did you check out that link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Comment: The answer not with tortoise git.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the following steps for avoid this issue.

At https://github.com/settings/tokens, go and generate a token.

While `git clone, push, pull` use the below credentials.

**username**: user_github_username

**password**: add_generated_token instead of the password.

Answer (score 58):

**Github Has Revoked the support for password authentication on 13 Aug 2021 and giving the below mentioned response:**

```
Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021
```

In order to fix the issue follow the below steps:

1. Goto settings of Github account
2. Find and Select Developer Settings
3. Find and Select Personal access tokens
4. Generate a new token
5. Fill in any note and select the access scopes
6. once done click on **generate token**

**Use the generated token in place of a password to communicate with GitHub.**

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: I was pushing some work after 4 years, it felt like self is frozen in time, but this answer helped me.

Comment: did not work in wsl2

Comment: I just use this way for my case, and wow, it still work. Tks so much bro!

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the git wants to store the token in the local machine instead of a password.

**So you can fix this issue on MAC**

1. Click on the profile picture
2. Goto the settings
3. then click "Personal access token and generate new token" as shown in the picture
   [image]
4. then write then token name + select expiration date and select the permissions that you want to give and then click on "Generate token present at the bottom of the screen"
   [image]
5. open the keychain access and search the github and double tap the github account
   [image]
6. final step is to paste the github token in the password field. That's all you have to do.
   [image]

Comment: From where we need to copy the token? i dont see the token in ur screenshot, I can only see the token name(note)

Comment: "Generate token present at the bottom of the screen"
in step 4

Comment: You don't need to put it in the keychain. Once you have created the token on Github, just rerun your git command and when prompt for the password, enter the just created token instead.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the below steps to solve the issue.

1. Update your git version using `git update-git-for-windows`
2. In the windows start button, search **Credential Manager** and open.
3. Click the **Windows Credential**, search and delete the GitHub credential.
4. Now using tortoise git, pull the code. You will get the below popup.

[image]

4. Click **Sign in with your browser** in the popup and now you can use tortoise git as like earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the token instead of password did not work for me. Here's all the steps I did:

1. Generate token in developer settings
2. Use the new token in all the places (Key Chain, Inside Intellij, In the terminal). Make sure you **save** the token somewhere because you cannot see it again, unless you regenerate it.
3. My organization had enabled **SAML SSO**. I went into the token and configured SSO and authenticated my organization. Steps for SAML SSO can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601439/organization-has-enabled-or-enforced-saml-sso-to-access-remote-this-repositor)

After following all the above 3 steps, I was able to successfully access git without password.

Answer (score 1):

****Just follow the simple three steps to push your repository in git...****

*before that you may run below command first*

> `git init`
> `git status`
> `git add .`
> `git branch -M main`

1. `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<repository_name>.git`
2. `git commit -am "your comments"`
3. `git push --set-upstream origin main`