# how to push git on debian 9

Tags: linux, git, debian

```
root@eyg-26955:~/FiveM/server-data# git push
Username for 'https://github.com': 0xj0n1
Password for 'https://0xj0n1@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/0xj0n1/GVNP_Server.git/'
```

I have already commited the code and now that appears

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the issue follow the below steps:

1. Goto settings of Github account
2. Find and Select Developer Settings
3. Find and Select Personal access tokens
4. Generate a new token
5. Fill in any note and select the access scopes
6. once done click on generate token
7. Use the generated token in place of a password to communicate with GitHub

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781928/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-on-august-13-2021)