# I can not upload anything to my repository on GitHub

Tags: git, upload

after this step is where I am having issues. I cannot get it to go through, extremely confused.

"git push -u origin main"
it asks me to put in a username and password of GitHub which is correct but still doesn't work.

Ive tried personal tokens, following videos on YouTube, searching stack overflow and inputting different code

Comment: And the error message you got? And the commands you run are? If you give no information, how do you expect to be helped? Pretty sure the reason is that you should use a personal token instead of your account password. Github documentation https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781928/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-on-august-13-2021)

Answer (score 0):

Support for password authentication was removed so I would recommend you to *reinstall* git with the latest version and then use git bash for your work
Configure user and email settings on git bash via commands

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "Your Email"
```

Configure your remote using command

```
git remote add origin "remote url or ssh"
```

and while pushing your code use same command

```
git push -u origin main
```

At this moment you will be prompted to **GUI** where you have to log in to your github account and then it might resolve the issue.