# Android Studio Get from VCS Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I've been trying to get android studio to clone a git repository, but I receive the error: 'Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server'. I've tried enabling credential manager in settings as many tutorials have stated, reinstalling git, and reinstalling Android Studio, but it doesn't appear to be working. Currently running Manjaro Linux 21.2.4. and Android Studio Stable 2021.1.1. However using Android Studio Canary it works as expected, prompting my username and password of the server. I am also not receiving this error on a Windows machine. Here is the full error. What do you think is causing this?

````
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:58)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:866)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:863)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.DefaultXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(DefaultXmlRpcTransport.java:87)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:27)
    ... 1 more
error: unable to read askpass response from '/home/user/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/tmp/intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.url.test': No such device or address```
````

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Comment: Try using the canary version of Android studio and see if that does anything

Comment: I got this error while pushing commit after updating Android studio to Chipmunk version, invalidate cache and restart did the trick for me. The new studio version also shows a dialog for invalidate cache, I kept the 'Clear VCS Log caches and indexes' checked.

Answer (score 5):

In MacOS, I fixed changing inside:

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Version control -> Git 
[Use credential helper] to enable (without this didn't allow me to save the git address).
```

Then on the top menu:

```
Git -> Git remotes then + 
Add your git https address
```

Now, in my case, git pull failed because it didn't had a tracked branch. But allowed me to choose an upstream branch in the event log - this showed me an empty branch. Then I selected master and check a check box (sorry, I can't remember what it said).

Comment: Any idea for windows? The similar steps are already done in my Android Studio. But still no luck!

Comment: I could fix the issue in Windows 11 by enabling this option

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue last week. I solved this with following steps:-

1. Installed latest version of Git on my PC(Windows)
2. Opened project home directory in Command Prompt
3. Then from my browser, I logged in to my bitbucket account and I created app password, which is now mandatory I guess. [Here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/) are the steps to create app password
4. I copied that password and went to command prompt again and executed git command (git push in my case)
5. I prompted for bitbucket password first, I entered the password
6. Then within cmd prompt I prompted for repository password, I entered the app password there
7. Git command ran successfully. After that, I am able to perform git actions from within Android Studio again
   Hope the same steps may help you too!

Comment: tried many things, but your solution worked like charm, the app password was not working in Credential Manager, but it worked in CMD. thanks

Comment: Yes, it's not working in credential manager, even in latest git version. For now, CMD is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Android Studio on a Mac) the Access Token had expired. All the suggestions described (including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508158/git-pull-failed-invocation-failed-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server)) did not work.
Only when I

1. deleted the expired user in the settings `Version Control > GitHub`.
2. then created the user with a new Access Token `log in with Token, Generate...`,
3. then cleared the VCS Log caches and indexes `File > Invalidate Caches... > Clear VCS Log caches and indexes`,

I was able to complete the pending push request successfully.