# Can't clone a flutter project - GitLab

Tags: android, git, flutter, android-studio, gitlab

I am trying to clone a flutter project in Android Studio, but unfortunately, Once I add the Git Url and hit clone button, It shows me processing dialog and after just 2 seconds it closed and showing me error as below :

[image]

What will be the possible solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Pull Failed: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508158/git-pull-failed-invocation-failed-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server)

Comment: No, Its about pull failed. I am talking about taking clone for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, We can use **Github Desktop** instead.

Just install it and you are good to go after logged in to your Git account.

Comment: You can also use SourceTree as it will work with various different version control tools like Github, Gitlab, BitBucket etc. Additionally, it provides functionality like globally saving credentials for different domains.

Answer (score 2):

Goto `Android studio -> settings -> VCS -> git ->` Tick Use `credential helper`

open terminal of andorid studio

use this command

```
git fetch
```

->  `git config --global credential.helper store <app password>`

and try to pull/clone  from android studio

EDIT

[image]

Comment: How can I go to Settings without opening my project, I have issue in just cloning the project, I still not opened my project. Issue is not with pulling or pushing, It comes when I trying to clone the project.

Comment: @JaiminModi : Check updated answer

Comment: I just done with the Tick for the option : credential helper. 
Now, How can I open terminal of android studio ?

Comment: you can use system's terminal also  @JaiminModi

Comment: I have done it by installing Github Desktop and cloned it. thanks